# How to change color of stars in zhanghai's MaterialRatingBar library I'm not able to find a way to do it?

Tags: java, android

Can anyone tell me how to change stars colour.I have tried backtracing in styles but couldn't find the color tag which it was using  instead it uses drwables for that.

```
 <me.zhanghai.android.materialratingbar.MaterialRatingBar
                android:id="@+id/avgRatingBar"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar.Indicator"
                android:layout_width="193dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/insideLocationMainImage"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="189dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp"
                android:isIndicator="true"
                android:numStars="5"
                android:rating="1"
                android:outlineAmbientShadowColor="@color/yellow"
                android:outlineSpotShadowColor="@color/yellow"
                android:stepSize="1"
                app:mrb_fillBackgroundStars="true" />
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the attribute app:mrb_progressTint="@color/tint"

https://github.com/zhanghai/MaterialRatingBar/blob/master/sample/src/main/res/layout/main_activity.xml

Answer (score 3):

You can use a style similar to this

```
<style name="RatingBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="mrb_progressTint">@color/Goldenrod</item>
    <item name="mrb_secondaryProgressTint">@color/Black</item>
    <item name="mrb_progressBackgroundTint">@color/Blue</item>
    <item name="mrb_fillBackgroundStars">false</item>
</style>
```

to change the colors of the Material Rating Bar.

[image]

In the above picture I've used three different parameters;

The first one has `mrb_progressTint=@color/White` so that one can see that there is always a thin border.

The second one has changed `mrb_fillBackgroundStars=true` that asks to fills the stars. Notice that the progress is always filled. Also, notice the half black star, too. So, the border color fills completely the star except the progressed ones. We can see this from the third picture that the golden still has a thin black border.